# Why can't I correctly group data in SQL?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to pull data and format [with these headers in this order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZPBf.png).

I'm pulling the data from Snowflake using SQL, and in the table I'm pulling the data from, the PD_amt and CN_amt are listed as separate transactions. Currently, when I pull the data, it still shows up as two separate lines with null values rather than being correctly grouped into a single row under a single user id; you can see it here in [the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avaRJ.png) (I highlighted a few rows to show the issue).

```
select atr.user_id
     , date_trunc('day', atr.trans_date) trans_day
     , atr.year_month
     , case when atr.trans_type = 'PD' then atr.trans_id end as PD_transaction_id
     , case when atr.trans_type = 'PD' then sum(atr.amount) end as PD_amt
     , case when atr.trans_type = 'CN' then atr.trans_id end as CN_transaction_id
     , case when atr.trans_type = 'CN' then sum(atr.amount) end as CN_amt
  from wisen_data.sm_account_trans atr
 where ((trans_type = 'CN' and trans_sub_type = 'HSNMLP')
         or trans_type in ('PP','PD'))
   and atr.status not in  ('VOIDED','FAILED')
   and atr.trans_date >= date_trunc('month', current_date-3*365)
group by atr.user_id, trans_day, atr.year_month, atr.trans_type, atr.trans_id
order by trans_day
```

I'm not super proficient with SQL so I'm hoping to get some quick help to get this to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Use conditional aggregation.  The `case` expression is the argument to the `sum()`:

```
select atr.user_id,
       date_trunc('day', atr.trans_date) as trans_day
       atr.year_month
       sum(case when atr.trans_type = 'PD' then atr.amount end) as PD_amt,
       sum(case when atr.trans_type = 'CN' then atr.amount end) as CN_amt
  from wisen_data.sm_account_trans atr
 where ((trans_type = 'CN' and trans_sub_type = 'HSNMLP')
         or trans_type in ('PP','PD')
       ) and
       atr.status not in  ('VOIDED','FAILED')
       atr.trans_date >= date_trunc('month', current_date-3*365)
group by atr.user_id, trans_day, atr.year_month
order by trans_day;
```

I removed `PD_transaction_id` and `CN_transaction_id` because I'm not sure what these are supposed to be.